# jQuery plugin - multiple instances, external invoking - master/slave relationships

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to wrap a canvas function in a jquery plugin, so that it can be invoked via multiple instances.

I want to be able to loop through found items and call the plugin like this

```
$('[data-init="multi"]').each(function( index ) {
   $(this).multiInstance("init");
});
```

but I need to be able to invoke different methods, pass arguments to these methods -- and then when a change has occurred - provide a callback to catch changes to the instance

http://jsfiddle.net/M99EY/62/

Comment: How do you ensure - your app will work in multiple instances --- and you can call methods for each or specific instances ---- if say creating a pie chart widget

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M99EY/69/  Is this the correct way of building the plugin... I want to be able to create multiple instances of the app -- but also control it externally - and also pull values out of it for external results.